# How to retrieve currency amount as words using oracle sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

In the below code, I am trying to get the amount in words for the value in the AMOUNT column but can't seem to get it right. Anyone with an idea? Below the CREATE VIEW statement:

```
SELECT GLR3 AS RECEIPT_DOC_NO,
   GLANI AS ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
   GLSBL AS JDE_NO,
   (SELECT YAALPH FROM PRODDTA.F060116 WHERE YAAN8 = T1.GLSBL) AS STAFF_NAME,
   CASE GLDGJ WHEN 0 THEN TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (1 + 1900000), 'YYYYDDD')         
      ELSE TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (GLDGJ + 1900000), 'YYYYDDD') END AS GL_DATE,
   GLEXA AS NARRATIVE,
   GLLT AS LEDGER_TYPE,
   GLSBLT AS SUBLEDGER_TYPE,
   GLCRCD AS CURRENCY_CODE,
   CASE GLAA WHEN 100 THEN ROUND (GLAA / 100, 2) ELSE ROUND (GLAA / 100, 2)
       END AS AMOUNT,
   (SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(T1.GLAA,'J'),'JSP')) FROM DUAL) AS AMOUNT_INWORDS         
FROM PRODDTA.F0911 T1;
```

My code is failing with

> ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected.

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: I have these two columns in my code. The first column has has an amount in kenyan currency while the second one is meant to display the amount in the first column in words in oracle sql as follows:

Comment: CASE GLAA
             WHEN 100 THEN ROUND (GLAA / 100, 2)
             ELSE ROUND (GLAA / 100, 2)
          END  AS AMOUNT,
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(T1.GLAA,'J'),'JSP') AS AMOUNT_INWORDS   FROM PRODDTA.F0911 T1;

Comment: i want to display 400 shillings in column two - in words using oracle sql script, but my code is failing at that point, complaining about ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected.

Indicates a syntax error. In this case you have three `(` and four `)`:

```
(SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(T1.GLAA,'J'),'JSP')) FROM DUAL) AS AMOUNT_INWORDS
```

The compiler is not expecting the second `)` after `'JSP'`.

The scalar cursor is unnecessary, so the simplified and corrected version would be:

```
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(T1.GLAA,'J'),'JSP') AS AMOUNT_INWORDS
```

---

> ORA-01854: julian date must be between 1 and 5373484

`5373484` is the Julian date for 31-DEC-9999 which is the maximum date allowed in Oracle. This poses an absolute limit on the number which we can spell using `JSP` mask ... in one go. However, we can use PL/SQL to break larger numbers into chunks and spell those instead. The inestimable Tom Kyte wrote such a function and published it on the AskTom site. [Find it here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1407603857650).

> I think the value i'm trying to write in words has decimal values (400.00) hence the ORA-01854 error.

The Tom Kyte I linked to does address that issue further down the page. [It's this comment here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/asktom.search?tag=spell-the-number#2561743214432).

---

> Data retrieved in amount column is preceded by a negative symbol when it shouldn't be,

If you simply want to ignore negative values then apply the `ABS()` function to give you the absolute value.

Comment: I guess it's hard to know if this question is about the syntax error or the logic for describing amounts or if OP expects us to fix both.

Comment: The syntax error got corrected, but now i'm getting this error: ORA-01854: julian date must be between 1 and 5373484

Comment: Thank you all for the responses. Data retrieved in amount column is preceded by a negative symbol when it shouldn't be, e.g. -400.00 so i'm getting an error when i use my function to write it in words. How do i get my query to read it as 400 because I'm getting an error...... CASE WHEN T1.GLAA > 0 THEN INITCAP (LIZ.NUMBER_TO_WORDS(to_char (T1.GLAA))) ELSE 'Zero' END AS AMOUNT_INWORDS